# Jbox2D isSensor for NPC collision

Tags: java, jbox2d

I have a 2D side scrolling game that's kind of like a metroid-vania, I have some NPC's I want to add, and I want to simulate them in the world with gravity and such(they collide with the floors) but I don't want them to collide with the player.

Setting the fixture to isSensor = true, causes the NPC's to fall through the floor, and setting it to false causes them to collide with the player.

Is there any way I can accomplish this without simulating a different World and then checking positions?

Comment: Couldn't you do something like:

`if(!whoiscolliding instanceof NPC)`

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't know how to disable collision on a case by case basis like that, Box2D assumes if you can collide with it, EVERYTHING can collide with it Sensors ignore all collision, and non sensor Dynamics collide with other Dynamics, Kinematics, and Static objects. If there is a way to do that I don't know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Box2D's built in filter you can filter collisions so that they do not collide

```
FixtureDef floorFixture
floorFixture.filter.categoryBits = 4

FixtureDef playerFixture
playerFixture.filter.catagoryBits = 2;
playerFixture.filter.maskBits = 4;

FixtureDef npcFixture
npcFixture.filter.catagoryBits = 2;
npcFixture.filter.maskBits = 4;
```

In this Example the Player and the NPC should not Collide with each other, but will collide with the floor.

Read more here(search for Filtering): http://www.box2d.org/manual.html